# Refresh a Jquery Mobile ListView every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Could somebody please explain how to refresh a jQuery Mobile ListView every 10 seconds or so? I know that there's the .refresh() method for the listview, so I'm more wondering how to go about writing the recurring method to call .refresh() every 10 seconds.

Any sample code you can provide would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    listview.refresh();
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var refreshData = setInterval(function() { $("#somelistview").refresh(); }, 10000);
```

in jqmobile you can run in onDeviceReady() or on the success if you are doing an ajax call

Comment: `setInterval` takes a function to run. So unless you've overridden `refresh` to return a function that, when run, will refresh the listview, this won't work. Sorry! :)